# Ansible check sha1sum

Tags: ansible

Have tryied to check sha1sum, but don't think is the right way to do it.

```
- name: "Check Sha1sum"
  stat:
    path: "/path/to/my/package.tar.gz"
    checksum_algorithm: sha1
    get_checksum: yes
```

Would check file sha1sum and compare the read sha1sum with a variable, is that possible?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What is the result and why do you think it is incorrect? What do you expect the result to be?

Answer (score 2):

> Q: **"*Check file sha1sum and compare the read sha1sum with a variable.*"**

A: For example, the play below will fail if the checksum of the file doesn't match the checksum stored in the variable *test_sha1*

```sh
shell> sha1sum /etc/passwd
7c73e9f589ca1f0a1372aa4cd6944feec459c4a8  /etc/passwd
```

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    test_sha1: 7c73e9f589ca1f0a1372aa4cd6944feec459c4a8
  tasks:
    - stat:
        path: /etc/passwd
      register: result
    - debug:
        var: result.stat.checksum
    - assert: 
        that: test_sha1 == result.stat.checksum
        fail_msg: '[ERR] Checkum failed.'
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
TASK [stat] ****
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ****
ok: [localhost] => 
  result.stat.checksum: 7c73e9f589ca1f0a1372aa4cd6944feec459c4a8

TASK [assert] ****
ok: [localhost] => changed=false 
  msg: All assertions passed
```

---

- In [stats](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/collections/ansible/builtin/stat_module.html#ansible-builtin-stat-retrieve-file-or-file-system-status) `checksum_algorithm=sha1` and `get_checksum=yes` are defaults.
- The checksum of the file will be returned in the attribute [stat.checksum](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/collections/ansible/builtin/stat_module.html#return-stat/checksum).
- See [assert](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/assert_module.html#ansible-builtin-assert-asserts-given-expressions-are-true).